# Waiting for a loop to finish before logging to the console

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm making a Discord Bot which will hook up to the ROBLOX API via the Bloxy.js Library.

I'm going through the friend list of an user and checking if a friend in their friend list is in one of the 4 groups aforementioned in the code - if it is, it stores the name in an array called "leoUsernames". Once the loop is done, I want it to log "All usernames logged." into the console.

But because I'm new to JS and JS doesn't run like the language I'm used to code in, I'm stuck and I don't know what to use to make it wait for the loop of checking the users to finish before outputting "All usernames logged."

Here is the code:

```
function CMD_LEOFRIENDS(message,args){
let leoUsernames = new Array();
if(isNaN(args[1])){
    bloxyClient.getIdByUsername(args[1]).then(userId =>{
    bloxyClient.getFriends({
        userId: userId, 
    }).then(friends=>{
        friends.map(totalfriends=>{
            let username = totalfriends.username
            let userId = totalfriends.userId
            bloxyClient.getUserGroups(userId).then(usergroups=>{
                usergroups.map(x=>{
                if(x.group.name == "Mayflower State Police" || x.group.name == "Plymouth Police Department" || x.group.name == "Lander Police Department" || x.group.name == "New Haven County Sheriff's Office"){
                leoUsernames.push(username)
                    console.log("Logging username: " + username)
                }
                }
            )
            })
        });
        console.log("All usernames logged.") })
})
}}
```

The expected result is to **log all usernames currently being logged to the console. When done logging, log "All usernames logged." to the console.**

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W1MY.png)

Comment: try searching for js promises or async/await

Comment: I have searched it, tried it but it all comes to the fact that I have no idea how to apply it to my code. But again, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your map, you are running a bunch of async code. Since that will all happen async, the map will finish its loops (though there will still be active promises waiting to finish) and then go immediately to the `console.log`. So, what you need to do is collect all the promises and wait for them collectively to finish. It's actually great that you're using `map` already, since that returns an array, though you aren't returning anything right now (and likely originally meant to use `forEach`).

So, what we can do is:

```
// NOTE: there's almost never a good reason to use `new Array` - it's much slower
let leoUsernames = [];

// NOTE: we save the items (promises) returned by the `map`
const friendPromises = friends.map(totalfriends => {
  let username = totalfriends.username;
  let userId = totalfriends.userId;

  // NOTE: here is where we return each promise
  return bloxyClient.getUserGroups(userId).then(usergroups => {
    // NOTE: use `forEach` here instead of `map`
    usergroups.forEach(x => {
      if (
        x.group.name == "Mayflower State Police" ||
        x.group.name == "Plymouth Police Department" ||
        x.group.name == "Lander Police Department" ||
        x.group.name == "New Haven County Sheriff's Office"
      ) {
        leoUsernames.push(username);
        console.log("Logging username: " + username);
      }
    });
  })
});

// NOTE: wait for all the promises to finish
Promise.all(friendPromises).then(() => {
  console.log("All usernames logged.");
});
```

Also, it's good practice to always use semi-colons in your code. While technically not needed in many cases, you can create some really hard to find bugs if you don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

It is cleaner if you can use async and await than using then. You then get to use normal loops normally.

```
async function CMD_LEOFRIENDS(message, args) {
  let leoUsernames = [];
  if (isNaN(args[1])) {
    let userId = await bloxyClient.getIdByUsername(args[1]);
    let friends = await bloxyClient.getFriends({
      userId: userId,
    });
    for (let totalfriends of fiends) {
      let username = totalfriends.username;
      let userId = totalfriends.userId;
      let usergroups = await bloxyClient.getUserGroups(userId);
      for (let x of usergroups) {
        if (x.group.name == "Mayflower State Police" || x.group.name == "Plymouth Police Department" || x.group.name == "Lander Police Department" || x.group.name == "New Haven County Sheriff's Office") {
          leoUsernames.push(username);
          console.log("Logging username: " + username);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("All usernames logged.");
}
```

Untested but looks like it could work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well but it was too slow, but it did work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const promise = files.map(async (file) => {
 

})
await Promise.all(promise);
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.